# Mask My Domain Name

Tags: wordpress, url, dns

I'm not sure if this is possible or what, I just thought about it.

I have a page in my site `www.mysite.com/thispage`

I want to change the whole URL of that page. 
`www.mysite.com/thispage` to `www.thispage.com` without transfering and configuring another set of files and databases..  My site is in wordpress. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure - depending on your hosting settings. You can buy the domain name "thispage.com" and then ask your hosting company to set it up to be hosted in the folder "thispage".

Just a heads up - usually hosting companies charge more to host a domain name like this (or host multiple domain names).

Then you'll need to edit the settings within Wordpress to reflect the new domain name (under SETTINGS).